# ViewController doesn`t display property FB/Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am using Parse and I want to show email taken from Parse and display in column in Parse. Everything like `first_name`, `last_name`, `id` etc. works fine. But when I try to set `prop.email` it doesn't find any property. If I do the same action in the place (tagged in the code), it finds me email property without any problems.

I mean this line of code:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.id forKey:@"fbid"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.first_name forKey:@"firstname"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.last_name forKey:@"lastname"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
//This one doesn`t find property email
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.email forKey:@"email"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

**The rest of FB connect`code**

```
{
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"email"];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        // Was login successful ?
        if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            }else {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
            // Callback - login failed
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commsDidLogin:)]) {
                [delegate commsDidLogin:NO];
            }
        }else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *prop = (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *)result;
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.id forKey:@"fbid"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.first_name forKey:@"firstname"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.last_name forKey:@"lastname"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:prop.email forKey:@"email"];
                    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
                 }else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
                    NSLog(@"Welcome Screen I am %@", [[PFUser currentUser] username]);
                 }
             }];
         } 
         else {
             //HERE
             NSLog(@"Error getting the FB username %@", [error description]);
         }
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        // Callback - login successful
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commsDidLogin:)]) {
            [delegate commsDidLogin:YES];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: And why are you calling save for every property?

Comment: `Property 'email' not found on object of type 'NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *` , Just want to display first name, last name and email. I think this is good way but just don`t understand, why it doesn`t display me this property, while all others( username,first_name atc.) are displayed without any problems

Comment: Did you try debugging the code and have a look at the prop object in the debugger to see what values it has?

Comment: That`s that, if I set a breakpoint in the line with Dictionary, it doesn`t crash even if I click button facebook and suecesfully log in

Comment: So, the code works with breakpoint, but not without???

Comment: I deleted line with ask for email. Then I made breakpoint and it seems like my app didn`t notice that there`s any breakpoint. Anyway if I am writing the code with setObject:prop.email, it doesn`t offer me email, just username,name etc. Looks like email doesn`t even exist. If I copy just the line with email(ofc I get error for no prop found), it offers me email. Do you understand, what I mean?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I don't understand why you can't set a breakpoint. Can't you set a breakpoint further up and then just step through until you get the prop object? You need to find out what the prop object contains. If it does not contain email, then you must look for the problem outside the provided code.

Comment: Everything other works, birthday, link, middle_name, id, username. I am sure that it doesn`t contains email

Comment: Finally breakpoints work. Got 15 items, but it shows me just 14 and there isn`t email

Comment: No idea what could cause that, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates a compile error because `email` is not defined in the [`FBGraphUser`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphUser/) protocol. So, you will need to find a different way to get the user e-mail from Facebook.

If you're using `PFSignUpViewController` and then later linking the account, ensure that the user enters an e-mail at that point in time.

Comment: I don`t use PFSignUpViewController, I made Log in/Sign up (Facebook, normal way) on my own. Isn`t there any other way how to get email from FB user? Because I don`t want to remake all my code.

Comment: Log `prop`, is the mail there, just not part of the protocol?

Comment: There`re props like timezone,gender,id etc. but email not.

Comment: Wain, right now I am doing log in with fb again. protocol doesn`t contain email prop. So the only way is to do it with PFSignUpViewController?